Let FullSimplify remove a sum-of-squares demoninator
I am trying to pre-process an ODE system for NDSolve, and the differential equation* have a structure like:
eq = (f[θ]/(Cos[θ[s]]^4 + θ'[s]^2)) == 0 (* θ'[s] > 0 *)

I tried to do
FullSimplify[eq, θ[s] ∈ Reals && θ'[s] != 0]

but it does not get rid of the overall denominator.
I am kind of clueless what a TransformFunction should I provide; or rather I use other built-in functions like Reduce?

Derivatives can also be complex, hence your assumption about θ'[s] != 0 is not enough for the simplification. Add θ'[s] ∈ Reals, then it works as expected.

θ[s] ∈ Reals does imply θ'[s] ∈ Reals from a human perspective. Is there a way to tell this to Simplify?

Try this:
Simplify[
 f[\[Theta][s]]/(
  Cos[\[Theta][s]]^4 + Derivative[1][\[Theta]][s]^2) == 
  0, {\[Theta][s] > 0, \[Theta]'[s] != 0, \[Theta]'[s] < \[Infinity], 
  f[\[Theta][s]] \[Element] Reals}]

(* f[\[Theta][s]] == 0 *)

Have fun!
